# first time network connection to s3 is time consuming

Tags: java, performance, networking, amazon-s3

I have a use case where i need to download multiple files from Amazon S3 in Java. The first time alone it takes more time ~800ms. The following 15 requests takes really less time less than 100ms. I am looking for below answers

1. Why it takes long time for the first time. Any time consuming network connection establishment?
2. Is it possible to pre-warm the network connection establishment?

I am using the org apache File Utils

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, new File(filename));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it has anything to do with S3.

First of all, start with verifying that DNS resolver is working properly. Try to `nslookup` or `dig` the corresponding host. How fast the FQDN is resolved?

Second, are you sure you need to warm up the connection, not the JVM? JVM might be slow on first executions of some code path. Try warming up JVM. Here some tips: http://www.baeldung.com/java-jvm-warmup.